# How do these variable references work?

Tags: javascript, object, prototypal-inheritance

Can someone please explain what's going on here? Thanks.

```
var o = {a:1};
var p = o;
o === p; // true;
o = Object.create(o);
p === o; // false
o.b = 2;
o.a; // 1
b.a; // 1
o.b; // 2
p.b; // undefined
```

What's going on? Especially in L4.  I'm assigning `o` in the current scope to the value of the assignment's RHS, in which o still points to the original object created on L1.  So then Object.create is latching onto the object itself, with absolutely nothing to do with the variable?

Comment: surely b.a = undefined??

Comment: `b.a` would be `ReferenceError` , I assume the OP meant `p.a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// create a new object and assign it to o
var o = {a:1};

// assign the value of o to the variable p
var p = o;

// o equals p because both variables refer to the same object
o === p; // true;

// create a new object which uses the existing object o as prototype
// overwriting the current value of o with the new object
// It's essentially the same as
// var tmp = {};
// tmp.__proto__ = o;
// o = tmp
o = Object.create(o);

// o and p refer to two different objects now
p === o; // false

// A new property is added to the object o
o.b = 2;

// inherited from the object that o originally referred to
o.a; // 1

// b is not defined anywhere (you probably meant p)
// p still refers to the object created in the first step
b.a; // 1

// the property b was assigned to the new object through o.b = 2
o.b; // 2

// the original object doesn't have a property b
p.b; // undefined
```

Comment: Hello Felix, is this "problem" caused by JS passing/assigning a value of the reference? So if you assign a variable to an object you can mutate that object through the variable but can't re assign the object by re assigning the variable. Not 100% sure on this but think some people get confused because in some languages you assign/pass strictly by value (can't mutate) or strictly by reference (can re assign).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your thoughts. I think it's just a general confusing about how objects work. In Java or Python you would experience the same. People don't seem to realize that in one situation, they are working with the value, e.g. mutating it (`foo.bar = 42;`) whereas in the other case they are modifying the container which holds the value (`foo = 42;`). Does this roughly go in the direction you were thinking of?

Comment: Yes, you hit the nail on it's head. For example:`org=[];copy=org;` you can change org through copy by mutating copy `copy.push("new");copy[1]="another";` but can't change org by re assigning copy. I guess for some this is confusing because it can be counter intuitive if you haven't programmed before or worse; programmed in a language that purely copies by value (org and copy are 2 separate objects and can't mutate each other) or purely by reference (re assigning copy changes value of org). Like C, http://denniskubes.com/2012/08/20/is-c-pass-by-value-or-reference/

Answer (score 3):

```
var o = {a:1};
var p = o;
```

So far you have 1 object and 2 variables pointing at it.

```
o = Object.create(o);
```

This line re-assigns variable `o` to a new (empty) object that is prototyped by `o`.

The previous object, currently `o`'s prototype, is still referred to by `p`.

The field reads go as follows:

```
o.a; // 1 - found in o's prototype (p)
b.a; // 1 - you probably meant p.a? found in p directly
o.b; // 2 - found in o directly
p.b; // not found in p or anywhere in p's prototype chain
```

Answer (score 1):

it is an example that showing the diffrence between DeepCopy and ShallowCopy

Object is a referenced type. means that when im creating object x, x only points to the memory where the object really is(like 0x0003f3)

by default, referenced typed object assignments(e.g Object x = a) are Shallow
that means when i have 2 referenced typed object like o and p
when i do the assignment p == 0 : both values reference to the same object !
the assingment copy only the memory offset and not the real object

means that every change you do on "p" will reflect to "o" aswell.
o == p is True because both holds the same pointer.

at line 4 : o is pointing to a different object and the rest just showing that changes to "o" doesnt reflect to "p" because they are no longer pointing to the same object in memory

Comment: No copying is taking place here at all. What you are describing (`p` and `o` referring to the same object) has nothing to do with shallow or deep copying. Shallow copying would be if I have an object `a` and an empty, different(!) object `b`, and I would copy all properties from `a` to `b`. Deep copying would involve doing this recursively so that value which are objects are "cloned" as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine someone being confused as to why p didn't change with o when re assigned.

You assign p to o and you'd think p is a reference to o because mutating o will mutate p but re assigning o would not re assign p (so not by reference?).

```
var o = {one:1};
p = o;
o.one="uno";//mutating o
o = {two:2};//re assigning o
console.log(p);//Object { one="uno"}
```

I think this because JS assigns and passes a value of the reference. Some people tell you by reference is impossible in JS and JS always passes by value. If this were true then you would not be able to mutate the passed/assigned value though. I think Python behaves in the same way.